# Как передать значение из QComboBox в QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, qcombobox

Есть ссылка:

```
r = requests.get('https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/TQBR/securities.json?iss.meta=off&iss.only=securities&securities.columns=SECNAME,SECID')
pricesale = (r.json()['securities']['data'])
```

По ней получаю значения из **`двух столбцов`** (название на русском и его английский аналог). Далее передаю русское название (через индекс [0]) в `QComboBox` и передаю то, что было выбрано в `QLabel`.

```
def comboBox(self):
        for i in pricesale:
            self.ui.comboBox.addItem(str(i[0]))
        self.ui.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
```

Мне нужно передать в `QLabel` английский вариант (индекс [1]) того, что было выбрано, а не русский

```
def onActivated(self,text):
        self.ui.label.setText(text)
        self.ui.label.adjustSize()
```

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pricesale** - это `<class 'list'>`:

```
[
    ['Абрау-Дюрсо ПАО ао', 'ABRD'], 
    ['АФК "Система" ПАО ао', 'AFKS'],
    ...
]
```

**data** - это `<class 'dict'>`:

```
{
    'Абрау-Дюрсо ПАО ао': 'ABRD', 
    'АФК "Система" ПАО ао': 'AFKS',
    ...
}
```

где 'русское название' - это ***ключ***, который нужен для `QComboBox`,
а 'английское название' - это ***значение***, которое нужно для `QLabel`.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.data = data
        self.comboBox = QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems([ k for k in data ])
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
        
        self.label = QLabel()
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        
    def onActivated(self, text):
        self.label.setText(self.data[text])
        

r = requests.get('https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/TQBR/securities.json?iss.meta=off&iss.only=securities&securities.columns=SECNAME,SECID')
pricesale = (r.json()['securities']['data'])
data = {i[0]: i[1] for i in pricesale}
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp(data)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что делает ``data = {i[0]: i[1] for i in pricesale}``

Comment: @Grechkin26 так мы делаем словарь. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @ S. Nick если не сложно опишите  вкратце как работает ваш вариант

Comment: @Grechkin26 я добавил некоторые пояснения в ответ